# How to get active tab position in android material

Tags: android, material-design

How to get active tab position in material tabs?
Any one help me.

Comment: where your code ? try with `setOnTabSelectedListener` ?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
                    new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                            super.onTabSelected(tab);
                            currentPage = tab.getPosition();

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
 tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(
                    new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(viewPager) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                            super.onTabSelected(tab);
                            position = tab.getPosition();

                        }
                    });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity implement OnTabChangeListener,
then set the listener for the TabHost `tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);`

```
@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String id) {
        Log.i("INDEX->", "Selected TAB Index - "+ tabHost.getCurrentTab());
}
```